# not able to apply css rules to parent elements only

Tags: html, css

I m having a list with ul and li s.

Now I want to apply a css rule to the parents only and not to the children.

For this I'm using the > symbol but that is applied to the children as well.

The example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pradyut/ubN68/3/)

The code I used at the css -

```
#nav > li a {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

The html being -

```
 <ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="Return home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="About the company">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">The product</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Meet the team</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="The services we offer">Services</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sevice one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sevice two</a></li>         
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="Our product range">Product</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Small product (one)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Small product (two)</a></li>                
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="Get in touch with us">Contact</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Out-of-hours</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Directions</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am still not sure what you want to achieve. Can you explain a little bit more? And FYI `>` is immediate child selector

Comment: the questions says-
"Now i want to apply a css rule to the parents only and not to the children."
And the right answer has been posted.

Comment: I can read what you wrote. May be you didn't understand what I wrote. The man who answered is a genius who understood.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use `#nav > li > a` which covers `a` children of the `<li>`.  Otherwise any `<a>` descendant of the `<li>` is also selected (which is everything).

Answer (score -1):

As of CSS3, there is no way to select an element based on its children. I *think* that something like that is coming in CSS4, but I'm not sure.

Small note: the `>` selector selects *only* the children, not the parents and the children.